# Rails - scopes and many-to-many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails application with movies and genres, where a movie has_many genres (comedy, action, drama etc) and a genre has_many movies. Obviously I have a join-table genres_movies, to keep track of the many-to-many relationships.

I am playing around with scopes to easily get movies without any genres - but I am not sure what the corresponding syntax is. Something like this does not work:

```
scope :no_genres, -> { joins(:genres).where(genres: { id: nil}) }
```

(I find relational databases confusing :)

Comment: Depending on Rails version you can use `left_joins` instead of `joins` (Older versions < 5.0 would be a bit more complicated due to the join table so I will leave this out of the comment for brevity). A LEFT OUTER JOIN will return all records from table A (left) and matching records from table B (right). In this case you are looking for the records in table A without a record in table B so your condition is correct "genres.id IS NULL" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar with relational databases then I should tell you that when you do a join, it selects the results where there is matching data.  So when you join movies with genres, the result is made up of where there is a movie and there is a genre and they match.  So where a movie has no genre it will not have a matching genre so it will not be in the result.

So what you want is a left outer join of `movies` on the left and `genres` on the right.  The left outer join will make sure that even a movie without a genre is in the result.  It will use NULL for all the values for the `genres` table in the result.  So if you then do the `where` with `id: nil` you will get only those records with no genres, and thus all the movies with no genres.

```
scope :no_genres, -> { left_joins(:genres).where(genres: { id: nil}) }
```

Comment: works like charm :) ... and yes I am ALWAYS getting confused with left_loin and outer_join and whathaveyou_join :) ... so thanks for the little piece of advise! :)